# Outlook REST API returns different itemId on mobile vs. desktop

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-js-helpers

From the [documentation,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) when retrieving `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`, if you are doing so from a mobile device (i.e., the `Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostname` is either `OutlookIOS` or `OutlookAndroid`), the `itemId` will already be properly REST-formatted. Otherwise you have to use `convertToRestId` when the hostname is `Outlook` or `OutlookWebApp`.

However, when requesting `itemId` on mobile and comparing it to the `itemId` that I receive on desktop after running `convertToRestId`, the results are very different:

> Mobile: IPeZKQ2zaYPXtQLOiL3jyYjYeDHZJM-WJk0FMdjqAKiAtTPcoynRaoUIjNPeFAobOzn4
>
> Desktop: WPbg0EnRleDtTlp7USABKGhveIZFyW6lxtopV1GvQAVeDWQVnkWn6IlPCPUtTEY45yUUgALcD8wFTIJTO43R2M0t1KZVg25jSjW2sxmvSSBQxHBImcjEuPkWiZs7M48qpwCT0judVYukJvDKEs8yNJT=

I replaced the actual IDs with gibberish except for the hyphen and equal sign; they do have the same length: 68 on mobile vs 152 on desktop.

The results are the same for desktop and Web app, and they are the same on mobile (Android and iOS).

The ID from mobile looks to be completely different from the ID retrieved from desktop. Is this intentional? The mobile IDs were formatted differently until a few months ago. Is there any way to change the mobile version to the REST IDs seen by the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Mobile now provides identifiers of type `restImmutableEntryId`.
Both the identifiers (converted identifier from desktop and identifier from mobile) should work with REST requests.

Incase you have a need to convert the type of identifiers, you can make use of [translateExchangeIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).